# Increasing size of VM hard disk fails with No free sectors

Tags: partitioning, virtual-machine, vmware, centos-7

I am following [this link](https://ma.ttias.be/increase-a-vmware-disk-size-vmdk-formatted-as-linux-lvm-without-rebooting/) to increase the size of my VM. I have increased the disk size (from 100GB to 200GB) by going to the Settings page of my VM.

```
~ $sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000ad9ca

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048   209715199   104344576   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 102.7 GB, 102680756224 bytes, 200548352 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 4160 MB, 4160749568 bytes, 8126464 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I am not trying to partition the unallocated space and I am getting `No free sectors available` when I run fdisk.

```
~ $sudo fdisk /dev/sda
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (2 primary, 0 extended, 2 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (3,4, default 3):
No free sectors available
```

Any suggestions on how I can overcome this error and update the disk size on my VM?

Answer (score 2):

A reboot of the VM helped. After a reboot, the new disk was seen when `fdisk -l` is performed.